# Powershell Loop Through Directory of Text Files and Append Filename + Last Line in new Text File

Tags: powershell, loops, append, text-files

I am wanting to iterate over a directory full of various text files, which have lines of content such as the below example:

> Mark.Stevens;Wed 03/11/2020; 8:02:23.83
>
> Paul.Robinson;Wed 03/11/2020; 9:52:24.78

And Filenames such as 'CII1234567.txt'.

And pull the filename along with the last line from the files themselves.

Currently I have the below code:

> $textfiles = (Get-ChildItem C:\Users\KP\Downloads\Test\Workstations | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq '.txt'}).FullName
>
> ForEach ($textfile in $textfiles) {
>
> Get-content $textfile -Tail 1 >> C:\Users\KP\Downloads\Test\Output.txt
>
> Get-content $textfile.Basename >> C:\Users\KP\Downloads\Test\Output.txt
>
> }

When I run the Powershell script it successfully grabs the content of each of the files such as:

> Mark.Stevens;Wed 03/11/2020; 8:02:23.83
>
> Paul.Robinson;Wed 03/11/2020; 9:52:24.78

However I have been having difficulty with successfully pulling the filename as well.

Ideally the resulting text file would look something like the below example:

> CII1234567.txt     Mark.Stevens;Wed 03/11/2020; 8:02:23.83
>
> CII1234567.txt     Paul.Robinson;Wed 03/11/2020; 9:52:24.78

Would anyone be able to help advise on how I can get the desired output?

Comment: Use foreach : Get-content $textfile -Tail 1 | foreach("$textfile;" + $_) >> C:\Users\KP\Downloads\Test\Output.txt

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to clarify on the full script perhaps? I tried modifying my script as you suggested but now nothing gets output to the file:
`$textfiles = (Get-ChildItem C:\Users\KP\Downloads\Test\Workstations | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq '.txt'}).FullName`
`ForEach ($textfile in $textfiles) {`
`Get-content $textfile -Tail 1 | ForEach("$textfile;" + $_) >> C:\Users\KP\Downloads\Test\Output.txt`
`}`

Comment: Each row of text file is a string.  So ["$textfile;" + $_ ] is just adding the text filename to the beginning of a string "$_" is the row of data.  Were you getting any output before change?  Why do you have two foreach?

Comment: Sorry I'm still very new to Powershell so forgive me for not following along completely, I had just appended your shared code in place of what I had in my original post for the line of content attempting to pull the filename, which has a ForEach above the code to pull the last line of text.
So far I've only had luck with an output when I only have the code for the last line (Tail -1); having the code for the filename results in no output in my testing so far.

Comment: I was able to get a version to export both that I can work with, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better you debug the code yourself.  I like writing code that is simple to debug.  When you try to put everything into one instruction you can't debug.  You can always use foreach in powershell to debug.  After you get code working you can combine statements if that is your style.  I like using Format-Table for debugging because it is great for enumerating through powershell object.

```
$children = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\KP\Downloads\Test\Workstations | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq '.txt'}
foreach($child in $children)
{
   $child | Format-Table
   foreach($textfile in $child)
   {
      $textfile | Format-Table
      foreach($row in $textfile)
      {
          "$textfile;" + $_  >> C:\Users\KP\Downloads\Test\Output.txt
      }
      
   }

}
```